# How to write a python program to accept http post requests in JSON format and respond back in JSON format?

Tags: python, json, django, mongodb

Mongodb and all related technologies but (in the last 2 weeks) I have learnt python, mongo db and have written code in python to read csv files, do data wrangling and write the date into mongodb. This part is done.

Now my app sends http requests in JSON format to get the data but I am not sure how to write a python code which listens to this http request, collect the query, fill up with answers and send back the data (answers) in json format. Should I use any frameworks like django or just a simple python program can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Listening for an HTTP request should be done by your web server.  I definitely would not recommend writing that part yourself.

If your application serves only a single request URL, with no user authentication, then it might be simple enough to write your own program from scratch.

But if it's more complex than that, i.e. if you want to serve multiple pages or you want your users to log in, I would recommend using a framework such as Django.

Comment: Thanks!! I guess I need to start with Django then. I wasn't sure I had to start with Django. Now I am :-) Any good tutorial to start with to write my first program in django? Thanks

Comment: The Django website has a good tutorial.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/